# ChartJS adding shadow color to grid and custom x-axis labels

Tags: chart.js

I'm using chartJS 2.6.0 with scatter. The code I use is as below:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/960.css" />
        <title>OCA-Test</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container_12">
            <canvas id="linechart"></canvas>
        <script>
var linedata = {
   datasets: [{
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0,
      borderColor: "black",
      borderWidth: [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
      pointBackgroundColor: ["blue", "blue","blue", "blue","blue", "blue","blue", "blue","blue", "blue"],
      pointRadius: [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5],
      pointStyle: ["rect","rect","rect","rect","rect","rect","rect","rect","rect","rect"],
      data: [
      {x: 0.25, y: 80},
      {x: 0.75, y: -14},
      {x: 1.25, y: -46},
    {x: 1.75, y: 30},
    {x: 2.25, y: 14},
    {x: 2.75, y: -20},
    {x: 3.25, y: -72},
    {x: 3.75, y: -56},
    {x: 4.25, y: -24},
    {x: 4.75, y: -52}
      ]
   }]
};
var chartOptions = {
   responsive: true,
   maintainAspectRatio: true,
   legend: {display: false},
   gridLines :{
       
   },
   scales: {
      yAxes: [{
         ticks: {
            beginAtZero: false,
            max: 100,
            min: -100
         }
      }],
    xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
            display: false
        }
    }]
   }
};
var lineID = document.getElementById("linechart").getContext("2d");
var lineChart = new Chart(lineID, {
   type: "scatter",
   data: linedata,
   options: chartOptions
});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I'm trying to do is to display some texts in the x-axis in the middle of every grid column like what the bar graph does see image [Bar graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdDfR.png)

Also, I would like to add a color to the grid just between y-axis -30 and 20 like in the capture below [HTML workaround](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t09aZ.png)

All I could do is do it in HTML by displaying

tags below the graph and using margins and by also placing an image in the background to get what shows in image 2 but it is an ugly solution.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For both requirements you can write custom inline plugins.

Example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [{
          x: 0.25,
          y: 80
        },
        {
          x: 0.75,
          y: -14
        },
        {
          x: 1.25,
          y: -46
        },
        {
          x: 1.75,
          y: 30
        },
        {
          x: 2.25,
          y: 14
        },
        {
          x: 2.75,
          y: -20
        },
        {
          x: 3.25,
          y: -72
        },
        {
          x: 3.75,
          y: -56
        },
        {
          x: 4.25,
          y: -24
        },
        {
          x: 4.75,
          y: -52
        }
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
        customText: {
        text: ['hi', 'this', 'is', 'text', 'in', 'Mid', '!', ':)'],
        size: '20px',
        color: 'red',
        font: 'Arial black'
      },
      backgrounds: {
        hbars: [{
            from: -28,
            to: -80,
            color: "rgb(195, 230, 195)"
          },
          {
            from: 20,
            to: 28,
            color: "rgb(230, 220, 195)"
          },
          {
            from: 0,
            to: 20,
            color: "rgb(230, 195, 195)"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [{
    id: 'backgrounds',
    beforeDraw: (chart, args, options) => {
      const {
        ctx,
        chartArea,
        scales
      } = chart;
      const y = scales['y-axis-1'];
      const x = scales['y-axis-1'];

      options.hbars.forEach((hBar) => {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.fillStyle = hBar.color;
        ctx.fillRect(chartArea.left, y.getPixelForValue(hBar.from), chartArea.right - chartArea.left, y.getPixelForValue(hBar.to) - y.getPixelForValue(hBar.from));
        ctx.restore();
      })
    }
  },
  {
    id: 'customText',
    afterDraw: (chart, args, options) => {
        const {
        ctx,
        chartArea,
        scales
      } = chart;
      const y = scales['y-axis-1'];
      const x = scales['x-axis-1'];
    
        options.text.forEach((text, i) => {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.font = `${options.size || '20px'} ${options.font || 'Arial'}`;
        ctx.fillStyle = options.color || 'black'
        ctx.fillText(text, x.getPixelForValue((Number(x.ticks[0]) + Number(x.ticks[1])) / 2), y.getPixelForValue((Number(y.ticks[i]) + Number(y.ticks[i + 1])) / 2))

        ctx.restore();
      })
    }
  }]
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
    <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow, it works great for the color but for labels in the middle of each grid column, you achieved that by changing the type to bar. I want to keep the type to scatter please.

Comment: Updated answer for you, not sure if you meant text in mid or on top, if you want it on top you just need to adjust the y where the text gets drawn

Comment: I'm sorry but I may miss-explained the request. I want to be able to insert text in the a-axis between 0 and 0.5 then between 1.0 and 1.5 and so on like in image 2 I attached not in the grid itself. That is what I reffered to bar type as it has text like that in the a-axis.

Comment: Updated again, if you want it different, you either have to provide a clear example or try to figure it out yourself with the code you have now

Comment: Sorry but I explicitly said like image 2. The text I'm looking for is not to be placed inside the grid but in the x-axis between each tick like between 0 & , 0.5 1 & 1.5 and so on. Here is the example https://ibb.co/s2LzqDt. I will figure it out myself. Thanks.